Are multi-element decks viable?
As I understood, multi-element decks apparently generate energy cards randomly. Is there a way to control this?
Because if the answer is no, a multi-element deck is just not viable. The game gives you this option for a reason...
There are cards that needs different energies, like Dragonair and Druddigon:


Do you have examples other than Druddigon, because if it's just Druddigon, my answer will be "it's not supposed to attack, it's just a Wall." https://www.reddit.com/r/PTCGP/comments/1hkbsjh/druddigon_a_guide_for_people_that_keep_asking_is/

@Malady I don't, I've started the game few days ago and I actually imagined that there were other cards like this. But the link you provided actually answers my problem, too bad I phrased the question in another way...

Well, I didn't write an answer yet, so you can edit the question still?

@Malady I found another card, this seems to be a Dragon-type's exclusive feature

The physical TCG, other digital versions based on the real TCG, has more card draw, and special energy that provides one energy of any type but only one at a time, along with Pokemon powers/attacks and trainers that have effects to "attach a (usually basic) energy from your discard pile to a " which help make multiple energy type decks viable. Insanity is an old classic I was hoping this game would get, but with 30 card decks they're unlikely to add much card draw or crazy stuff unless it gets expanded.

Note: I've only been playing TCG Pocket for a few weeks and don't have any experience with the physical TCG game. Also, the meta will shift over time, so this answer may cease to be viable in the future.
Regarding multi-element decks, unless you are specifically building around a Pokémon that requires multiple elements in order to attack, I would highly advise against opting for a multi-element play style. You are adding a new type of RNG to a game where luck already plays a large role, and yes, I have had games end because my Dragonite stared down six consecutive electric energies.
The best ways to work with multi-element attackers are to pair them with Pokémon that either utilize any energy type or Pokémon that don't require much energy, or supplement them with reliable attackers of one of the types needed. Right now, the Misty card is capable of supporting a more water-heavy play style as well (though it is pure RNG), but not all elements have this type of support.
In the future, as the meta changes, there may be more uses for multi-element decks. And, of course, if you use Pokémon that can generate energy regardless of the energy type you get each turn, those can open up new strategies as well.

Ok, so a full-electric team with Dragonite + Misty to provide water energy when needed should be more viable

Note: Misty can only be used on Water type Pokémon; her card cannot be used to give energy to the Dratini Line.

Eh, nevermind then...

It's a bit specific, but Druddigon should just be used as a spiky wall for your enemies to bump into, stalling them for a bit.

The Genetic Apex Dragonair is part of an evolutionary line that's all about Water/Electric, as seen with Dratini and Dragonite.
There's a video guide  for how to use Dragonite, which, at the end, seems to be just "Use Misty and Lapras as alternate attackers" to use up extra Water Energy.
Other guides / decks stall with 'mons who don't need energy to be useful, like Weezing + Koga or Hypno, to poison / sleep respectively, just as prep, building up Energy and ending the battle with Dragonite, instead of using it early.
So, for the Dragonite line, it seems the discovered strat is "Stall and use Dragonite as a beatstick, but beware of Sabrina".

A majority of the links you provided are other TCG guides. The question is asking about TCG Pocket, which was only released October 2024. So a majority of the cards in the guides aren't available in TCGP

@Wondercricket - Ah, I see. https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trading_Card_Game_Pocket#Differences_from_the_TCG

@Wondercricket - Well, found a video guide for Dragonair.
